# java midlet for touch screen

Tags: java, java-me, touch, midlet

Can somebody please guide me on how can i test my application JAD on touch screen emulator in Linux environment.Is there any touch enabled emulator to test applications?
The JAD is currently not showing softkey labels on touch screen phones.I have already tested it including attribute MIDlet-Touch-Support: True,but its stil not showing commands on touch screen devices.
I have searched a lot and still clueless.Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the emulator property 
Edit your XXXPhone.property in wtklib\devices\XXXPhone directory

By default the touch_screen is set to false, set it to true,

now you should be able to use touch enabled application in your emulator.